# 'Invalid number of arguments for function replace. Expected: one of 2 and 3; Found: 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running pyspark script and getting the above error.

I am trying to run this sql query:

sql query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT id AS id, nm AS addr_line1, addr_line2, vw_addr.city, 
       vw_addr.state, vw_addr.zip, vw_addr.country, 
        UPPER(
          REPLACE(
            CONCAT(nvl(vw_addr.nm,''),
                   nvl(vw_addr.addr_line2,''),
                   nvl(vw_addr.city,''),
                   nvl(vw_addr.state,''),
                   nvl(vw_addr.zip,''),
                   nvl(vw_addr.country,''),' ','')
                 )
               ) AS addr_key, 
       prmry_addr AS prmry_addr_flg, inactv AS inactv_flg, del_flg, record_type_id, 
       from_utc_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'EST5EDT') AS im_insert_dt 
  FROM vw_addr
```

Error:

> 'Invalid number of arguments for function replace. Expected: one of 2 and 3; Found: 1; line 1 pos 121'

Comment: python / pyspark tags removed, it's purely a SQL issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. You're only passing one argument to `REPLACE`:

```sql
UPPER(
    REPLACE(
       CONCAT(
         nvl(vw_addr.nm,''),
         nvl(vw_addr.addr_line2,''),
         nvl(vw_addr.city,''),
         nvl(vw_addr.state,''),
         nvl(vw_addr.zip,''),
         nvl(vw_addr.country,''),
         ' ',
         ''
       )
    )
)
```

If you arrange your parentheses differently, you get something that makes sense:

```sql
UPPER(
    REPLACE(
       CONCAT(
         nvl(vw_addr.nm,''),
         nvl(vw_addr.addr_line2,''),
         nvl(vw_addr.city,''),
         nvl(vw_addr.state,''),
         nvl(vw_addr.zip,''),
         nvl(vw_addr.country,'')
       ),
       ' ',
       ''
    )
)
```

so that the `' ',''` are arguments to `REPLACE` instead of extra arguments to `CONCAT`.

Answer (score -1):

It's now working for me instead I have used the same parameter again in my code under the if() function.

```
sqlContext.sql('select  current_batsman , 
(sum(batsman_runs)/count(IF(is_wicket = 1,is_wicket = 1,is_wicket = 
1)))*100 as Strike_rate from Entire_dataset_table  where current_over 
between 1 and 6 AND NOT extras_type = "noballs" "penalty" "wides" GROUP 
BY current_batsman ORDER BY Strike_rate DESC Limit 1' ).show()
```

Comment: Your answer was not related the question.